# How can automatically wrapped to a new line the text inside an HTML table cell?

Tags: html, css, xhtml, html-table

I have the following problem in HTML.

I have this table that contains only a thead:

```
<table border="1" class="table_legenda" width="100%">

    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th width="8.33%">Codice</th>
        <th width="2%">Stato</th>
        <th width="8.33%">Creazione<</th>
        <th width="8.33%">Registrazione</th>
        <th width="6.33%">Autore Cr</th>
        <th width="6.33%">Autore Con</th>
        <th width="6.33%">Autore Acq</th>
        <th width="8.33%">Totale Imponibile</th>
        <th width="24.66%">Fornitore</th>
        <th width="4.33%">RM riserva</th>
        <th width="8.33%">Errore</th>
        <th width="8.33%">Azione</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Now, as you can see, every th cell have setted a percentual width and contains a textual value.

My problem is that if the textual value of a cell is longer than the available space of the cell it will be automatically hidden. I want that the text is automatically wrapped to a new line.

How can I do to obtain this behavior?

Tnx

Comment: Like this you mean ? - http://jsfiddle.net/js1zjm0x/

Comment: The code posted does *not* cause text to be hidden. Instead, columns are set wide enough. The `width` settings are taken just as suggested minimum widths. Text will automatically wrap between words when needed, unless you somehow prevent it. Please post a case that actually demonstrates the problem, and explain what you regard as permissible line breaking. (Between words? Inside words with hyphenation? Barbarically at arbitrary points?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to set the table to have a `table-layout:fixed` and the `th` elements to be `overflow-wrap:break-word`

```css
.table_legenda {
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.table_legenda th {
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<table border="1" class="table_legenda" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th width="8.33%">Codice</th>
      <th width="2%">Stato</th>
      <th width="8.33%">Creazione</th>
      <th width="8.33%">Registrazione</th>
      <th width="6.33%">Autore Cr</th>
      <th width="6.33%">Autore Con</th>
      <th width="6.33%">Autore Acq</th>
      <th width="8.33%">Totale Imponibile</th>
      <th width="24.66%">Fornitore</th>
      <th width="4.33%">RM riserva</th>
      <th width="8.33%">Errore</th>
      <th width="8.33%">Azione</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

---

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/ma4bc7zj/

Comment: ok, it is very interesting but I want to wrap using entire word and not in the middle of a word. Can I do it?

Comment: @AndreaNobili, why did you accept the answer when it breaks things (words) in a clearly unacceptable way (as you say)?

Comment: @AndreaNobili your initial code will exhibit the behaviour you describe. It will auto wrap between words if they do not fit in a single line.